# When do we use launch(SupervisorJob())?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have seen tutorials passing `SupervisorJob`to `CoroutineScope` to avoid all coroutine jobs being cancelled if one of its child fails.
In `run3`, I thought passing `SupervisorJob` to `launch` can get the same result, but apparently it does not. It seems to allow the Coroutine to be reused if there is an exception (if you remove the `SupervisorJob` from `launch`, second `run2` call won't run the coroutine job), but it dose not behave like `supervisorScope`, whose other children job can continue (in the example the first `test1.run` call) . I wonder in what scenario we can use this way? Because it looks legit to pass it to `launch` constructor.

```
package coroutine.exceptions

import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun log(msg: String) = println("$msg (${Thread.currentThread().name})")

val logExceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
    log(e.localizedMessage)
}

fun main() = runBlocking {

    TestReuseCoroutineAfterException4("test1").run {
        run1(true)
        delay(100)
        println()

        run1(false)
        delay(100)
    }

    println("================================================================")

    TestReuseCoroutineAfterException4("test2").run {
        run2(true)
        delay(100)
        println()

        run2(false)
        delay(100)
    }

    println("================================================================")

    TestReuseCoroutineAfterException4("test3").run {
        run3(true)
        delay(100)
        println()

        run3(false)
        delay(100)
        println()
    }

    log("finished")
}

class TestReuseCoroutineAfterException4(
    private val testName: String
) : CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(CoroutineName(testName)) {

    // by passing a Job, we can let the exception propagate to this coroutine scope instead of the
    // root one, which allows us to reuse the root scope.
    fun run1(throwException: Boolean) = launch(logExceptionHandler + Job()) {

        val logPrefix = "$testName.run1:"

        coroutineScope {

            launch {

                launch {
                    if (throwException)
                        throw RuntimeException("$logPrefix throw exception")
                    else
                        log("$logPrefix done (job#1-1)")
                }.join()

                launch {
                    log("$logPrefix done (job#1-2)")
                }.join()


                log("$logPrefix done (job#1)")

            }.join()

            launch {
                log("$logPrefix done (job#2)")
            }.join()
        }
    }

    suspend fun run2(throwException: Boolean) {

        val logPrefix = "$testName.run2:"

        supervisorScope {

            launch(logExceptionHandler) {

                launch {
                    if (throwException)
                        throw Exception("$logPrefix throw exception")
                    else
                        log("$logPrefix done (job#1-1)")
                }.join()

                launch {
                    log("$logPrefix done (job#1-2)")
                }.join()


                log("$logPrefix done (job#1)")

            }.join()

            // this will be run.
            launch {
                log("$logPrefix done (job#2)")
            }.join()
        }

    }

    fun run3(throwException: Boolean) {

        val logPrefix = "$testName.run3:"

        launch(logExceptionHandler + SupervisorJob()) {

            launch {

                launch {
                    if (throwException)
                        throw Exception("$logPrefix throw exception")
                    else
                        log("$logPrefix done (job#1-1)")
                }.join()

                launch {
                    log("$logPrefix done (job#1-2)")
                }.join()


                log("$logPrefix done (job#1)")

            }.join()

            // this will still be run.
            launch {
                log("$logPrefix done (job#2)")
            }.join()
        }

    }

}
```

output

```
test1.run1: throw exception (DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @test1#2)

test1.run1: done (job#1-1) (DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @test1#7)
test1.run1: done (job#1-2) (DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @test1#8)
test1.run1: done (job#1) (DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @test1#6)
test1.run1: done (job#2) (DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @test1#9)
================================================================
test2.run2: throw exception (main @coroutine#10)
test2.run2: done (job#2) (main @coroutine#12)

test2.run2: done (job#1-1) (main @coroutine#14)
test2.run2: done (job#1-2) (main @coroutine#15)
test2.run2: done (job#1) (main @coroutine#13)
test2.run2: done (job#2) (main @coroutine#16)
================================================================
test3.run3: throw exception (DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @test3#18)

test3.run3: done (job#1-1) (DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 @test3#22)
test3.run3: done (job#1-2) (DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 @test3#23)
test3.run3: done (job#1) (DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 @test3#21)
test3.run3: done (job#2) (DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 @test3#24)

finished (main @coroutine#1)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if you remove the `SupervisorJob` from `launch`, second `run2` call won't run the coroutine job

The reason for this behavior is not that you are passing a `SupervisorJob`, but that you are passing *any* kind of `Job` to it. Try replacing `+ SupervisorJob()` with `+ Job()` and the second invocation of `run2()` will execute the coroutines.

The main difference is that, when you pass an explicit job to `launch`, it becomes the parent job of the launched coroutine instead of the master job within `TestReuseCoroutineAfterException4`. Coroutine failure therefore doesn't cancel the master job and the effects are localized to a single invocation.

Passing a job directly to `launch` is not an encouraged practice because it breaks structured concurrency and creates the weird semantics that you experienced.

Comment: But by passing Job to launch it actually solves my problem. I want to call a function and inside that function I can capture any exceptions from children coroutine jobs (including nested children ones), and reuse the coroutineScope. I finally found the way I want which is like the `run1` function which I just added. I don't know if that is a good practice?

Comment: What's wrong with `try { coroutineScope { ... } } catch (e: Exception)`?

Comment: Didn't realize you can use try catch! Thank you I have come up with a better solution for my case.