# Kotlin SupervisorJob unexpected behaviour

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the next code:

```
import kotlin.coroutines.*;
import kotlinx.coroutines.*;

val job = SupervisorJob()
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
    println("Catch: $e")
}
val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO + job + handler

fun main() {
    val job1 = GlobalScope.launch(coroutineContext) {
        // supervisorScope {
        launch { 
            println("Test0")
            for (i in 0..5) { 
                println("Working! Iteration: $i")
                delay(1000)
            }
            println("Test0 end")
        }


        launch { 
            println("Test1")
            delay(2000)
            throw IllegalAccessException()
        }

        launch { 
            println("Test2")
            delay(3000)
            println("Test2 end")
        }

    }
    //}
    runBlocking { job1.join() }
    println("Test3")
}
```

As You can see, I'm using `SupervisorJob` by passing it in `coroutineContext` into `GlobalScope.launch` to avoid canceling of any children on error if it happened anywhere and error must be handled in `handler`. The documetation says next about `SupervisorJob`:

```
Creates a supervisor job object in an active state. Children of a supervisor job can fail independently of each other.
```

Based on this, I'm expecting something like that:

```
Test0
Working! Iteration: 0
Test1
Test2
Working! Iteration: 1
Catch: java.lang.IllegalAccessException
Working! Iteration: 2
Working! Iteration: 3
Test2 end
Working! Iteration: 4
Working! Iteration: 5
Test0 end
Test3
```

But I get:

```
Test2
Test0
Working! Iteration: 0
Test1
Working! Iteration: 1
Catch: java.lang.IllegalAccessException
Test3
```

The only that helps is uncomment `supervisorScope` in code above.

What I'm doing wrong? How I can set expected behaviour globaly in `ViewModel`, for example, to avoid wrapping every `launch` in `supervisorScope`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Summary of linked issue: when you pass an explicit job to `launch`, it replaces the job found in your  `coroutineContext` as the parent job. Coroutine failure therefore doesn't even reach the master job (it may be a plain `Job`, no difference), but it _does_ cancel the `launch`ed coroutine, which is the parent of everything inside it.

Comment: He passes an explicit job only to the root `launch`, so it replaces only `GlobalScope`'s job which isn't used anywhere. If you write `val job1 = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch {` it won't fix anything, even though there are no explicit jobs in any `launch`es.

Comment: This question is more about creating an instance of `CoroutineScope` that handles child cancellation like a scope created by `supervisorScope` builder, so the code can be `launch`ed straight in this scope without need to wrap it into `supervisorScope` block. As far as I can see, `CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())` still cancels all its children if one of them is cancelled.

Comment: @ardenit There is no such thing as a `GlobalScope`'s job. `GlobalScope` holds an empty `coroutineContext`

Comment: `CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob()) still cancels all its children if one of them is cancelled`---and the reason is that the job of the `launch`ed coroutine is never a `SupervisorJob` or anything else you supply from the outside. It is always a `StandaloneCoroutine` and the passed-in job is its parent.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, so, if I want this behaviour for `viewModel`, for example, I need implement `CoroutineScope` with `coroutineContext` error handler for whole scope and then pass new `Job()` to every new `launch` in this scope?

Comment: You shouldn't pass any `Job` instances to `launch`. Just use `viewModelScope.launch` so all the coroutines get cancelled when the view-model is done. And no need for the top-level coroutine that you have in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MarkoTopolnik, solution that worked for me:

```
val job = SupervisorJob()
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
    println("Catch: $e")
}
val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO + job + handler
val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)

fun main() {
    val job1 = coroutineScope.launch {
        println("Test0 start")
        for (i in 0..5) {
            println("Test0 iteration: $i")
            delay(1000)
        }
        println("Test0 end")
    }

    val job2 = coroutineScope.launch {
        println("Test4 start")
        for (i in 0..5) {
            println("Test4 iteration: $i")
            delay(1000)
        }
        println("Test4 end")
    }

    val job3 = coroutineScope.launch {
        println("Test1")
        delay(2000)
        throw IllegalAccessException()
    }

    val job4 = coroutineScope.launch {
        println("Test2 start")
        delay(4000)
        println("Test2 end")
    }

    val jobs = mutableListOf(job1, job2, job3, job4)
    runBlocking { 
        jobs.forEach { it.join() } 
    }

    println("end")
}
```

Result:

```
Test0 start
Test0 iteration: 0
Test1
Test4 start
Test4 iteration: 0
Test2 start
Test0 iteration: 1
Test4 iteration: 1
Test0 iteration: 2
Test4 iteration: 2
Catch: java.lang.IllegalAccessException
Test4 iteration: 3
Test0 iteration: 3
Test2 end
Test4 iteration: 4
Test0 iteration: 4
Test4 iteration: 5
Test0 iteration: 5
Test4 end
Test0 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60026536/1103872), you can't change the type of the job for a launched coroutine. The only thing under your control is its *parent* job. Since you first launch a top-level coroutine and then, as its children, launch those whose failure you don't want to influence the others, the best option is what you already discovered, opening an inner `supervisorScope`.

You cannot specify a global policy on how a given coroutine will behave upon the failure of its children.